# Mass conservation in a distribution sense.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, distribution-theory, fluid-dynamics

I have been reading T. Tao's physical derivation of Navier-Stokes equation (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/09/03/254a-notes-0-physical-derivation-of-the-incompressible-euler-and-navier-stokes-equations/) and have some trouble with starting point (11) and its momentum counterpart. As I understand, due to mass conservation, you have that  $ \int_{R^{d}}\psi(t,x)d\mu_{mass}(t)(x) = C$, ($\psi$ is a test function and C constant) so deriving and integrating you obtain (11). But I can not realize why this (equation I typed above) should be a consequence of mass conservation. Is there a physical interpretation of test function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From where do you get $\int_{R^{d}}\psi(t,x)d\mu_{mass}(t)(x) = 0$? In eq. (11) and (12) there is a time derivative.

Comment: Sorry, I should have write $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\psi(t,x)d\mu_{mass}(t)(x) = C$ with C constant.